# use specific kendo chart library files instead of kendo.all.min.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo chart in my application, for this "kendo.all.min.js" is used
but size of this file is 2.5 MB, and i want to optimize the speed performance of application therfore i want only specific kendo chart library,

I am using following library instead of kendo.all.min.js.

```
<script src="scripts/kendo/kendo.core.min.js"></script> 
<script src="scripts/kendo/kendo.data.min.js"></script>  
<script src="scripts/kendo/kendo.userevents.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/kendo/kendo.color.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/kendo/kendo.pdf.min.js"></script> 
<script src="scripts/kendo/kendo.drawing.min.js"></script> 
<script src="scripts/kendo/kendo.dataviz.core.min.js"></script> 
<script src="scripts/kendo/kendo.dataviz.themes.min.js"></script> 
<script src="scripts/kendo/kendo.dataviz.chart.min.js"></script> 
<script src="scripts/kendo/kendo.dataviz.chart.polar.min.js"></script> 
<script src="scripts/kendo/kendo.dataviz.chart.funnel.min.js"></script>
```

And When i run application it throws error "Origin are not define"

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
                 legend: {
                     position: "bottom",
                     item: {
                         visual: createLegendItem
                     }
                 },
                 seriesDefaults: {
                     type: "line",
                     style: "smooth",
                     visual: function (e) {
                         return createColumn(e.rect, "#6e6e78");//#0099CC")// e.options.color);
                     }
                 },
                 series: [{
                     type: "column",
                     data:  a,b,c,d,
                     labels: {
                         visible: true,
                         position: "outsideEnd",
                         visual: function (e) {
                             console.log(e); 
                             var rect;
                             //if (checkScreenSize()) {
                             //    rect = new kendo.geometry.Rect(
                             //      [e.rect.origin.x, e.rect.origin.y],  // Position of the top left corner
                             //      [25,25] // Size of the rectangle
                             //    );
                             //} else { 
                             rect = new kendo.geometry.Rect(
                             [e.rect.origin.x - position, e.rect.origin.y],  // Position of the top left corner
                             [size, size] // Size of the rectangle
                           );....
```

Please let me know where i am wrong and which files i missed to include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use kendo.custom.min.js file before above files, it will work